# Unable to connect ethernet by dongle

Tags: arch-linux, usb, ethernet, manjaro

I was looking to move from wifi to ethernet. My computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon Gen II. This computer does not have an ethernet port. You have to rely on a dongle. I still own the one shipped with the computer 
(it looks like [this](https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8585/16769857511_c74131e669_c.jpg)). Since mine is a bit damaged over the time. Today, I bought a [new one](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B00M77HMU0/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) (a usb to rj45 adapter) on Amazon. I cannot find a way to make it work. Any help is welcome.

end of hostnamectl:

```
Operating System: Manjaro Linux
Kernel: Linux 4.4.83-1-MANJARO
Architecture: x86-64
```

output of ifconfig enp0s25:

```
enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 54:ee:75:96:39:28 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
device interrupt 20 memory 0xf0500000-f0520000
```

output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-V (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

output of lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04ca:7036 Lite-On Technology Corp.
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1058:107c Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements Desktop (WDBWLG)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bc2:a0a4 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Desktop Drive
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bc2:a0a4 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Desktop Drive
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:0169 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Try: `ifconfig enp0s25 up` (enable the interface) and then `dhcpcd` (run dhcp client to obtain ip address). If this works, you then can use a service or utility that does that and more for you. E.g.: netctl.

Comment: Please indicate which entry in `lspci` and `lsusb` corresponds to the wireless dongle. If you are buying a new piece of hardware, it's a good idea to check Linux compatibility before buying it rather than afterewards.

Comment: @rudib it worked! Can you write an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In order to test if the connection is working:

`ifconfig enp0s25 up` (this enables your network interface/the dongle)

`dhcpcd`              (this starts a dhcp client in order to obtain an ip address)

## When this works you can move to a more permanent and convenient solution:

For example, you can use netctl in order to automatically connect.
What you have to do:

- Create a profile in `/etc/netctl/my_dhcp_profile` or how you like to name it; you can create multiple ones too. Such as:

  ```
   Interface=enp0s25
   Connection=ethernet
   IP=dhcp
  ```

  **or** (Static IP):

  ```
  Interface=enp0s25
  Connection=ethernet
  IP=static
  Address=('10.1.10.2/24')
  Gateway=('10.1.10.1')
  DNS=('10.1.10.1')
  ```
- Enable the Profile:

  ```
  netctl enable my_dhcp_profile
  netctl start my_dhcp_profile
  ```

After that, it will be automatically activated when available and should not require further interaction.
The `start` basically is required in order to start it up now and not after a reboot. You can also use `stop` to manually deactivate it.